# Simulink style block diagram drawing in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, block, simulink, diagrams

Hello fellow developers,
I am working on a Digital Communication System Simulator using Visual Basic .NET.
I want the simulator to be more graphical rather than writing code to represent each of the blocks in the system. I am embedding IronPython to make it  customizable. Also the tool is plugin supported where each of the pluggable communication blocks are designed in VB/C# and compiled into a .NET assmebly which will be loaded at runtime by the tool. All i need now is a way to allow the user to graphically insert/modify/connect these blocks to design a system like in Simulink.
 It should be similar to simulink's data flow graphical programming environment. Take a look at this image - http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/Content/Basics/figures/SimulinkBasicsTutorial_BuildingSystems_FinalModel.png. I want to know if there are any tutorials or references on this.

Comment: Can you give more details about what you've already tried, and what kind of help you're looking for?

Comment: _"All i need now is a way to ..."_ What issue are you facing right now ?

Comment: I really have not much idea about drawing. I know how to draw lines and shapes using GDI+. But i need movable lines and shapes. And i must be able to connect two rectangular boxes using lines. On moving the boxes, the lines should re-reroute.